# How do I generate JavaDocs for non-exported packages in a module?

Tags: java, maven, module, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am currently writing a JavaFX application contained within 1 module and I want to use Javadoc to document all of my code. However, I am noticing that I can't seem to generate Javadocs for packages that have not been exported out of the module in `module-info.java`. On one hand, that makes sense. Non-exported packages aren't part of the public API. On the other hand, I feel like *surely* there should be options to enable documentation of internal APIs hidden in non-exported packages, but I've had no success in enabling them.

As this is a Maven project, I've tried the following options with the maven-javadoc-plugin:

1. `<show>private</show>`
2. `<additionalOptions>-private</additionalOptions>`
3. `<additionalOptions>--show-module-contents all --show-packages all --show-types private</additionalOptions>`

None of these work (and I am pretty sure 1 and 2 are the exact same thing). They only show a bit more info on one package that i've exported to another specific module. If I don't have these options, the Modules section of the Javadoc is completely blank with the exception of the module name.

I've done lots of Googling and no one on the Internet seems to bring this issue up. Maybe my Google-Fu is just off? I feel like there's just some silly undocumented flag that I haven't found yet because it can't be the case that you *have* to export the packages to get Javadocs for them, right?

My project consists of only one module containing 8 packages. None of them need to be fully exported out yet. Only one package containing my JavaFX files needs to be exported to `javafx.graphics` and that's the only one that gets picked up by Javadoc when I enable `<show>private</show>`.

Here is a gist of my module and Maven config, if anybody needs it:
https://gist.github.com/urbenlegend/753de7bec598fd07d6b5c0b0ef02d1d0

I am invoking Javadoc generation via `mvn compile javadoc:javadoc`

Anyone here have any tips? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm facing the same issue. Thanks.

Comment: I have not been able to get a straight answer from anywhere regarding this. Really frustrating.

Comment: I wound up simply making all my modules public just so I could Javadoc them. I think this is probably not what they intended, but it seems to be the only workaround.